# How to delete a specific file, in a specific location, if the file is larger than given size, in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, command, dos

How to delete a specific file, in a specific location, if the file is larger than given size, in a batch file.

Basicly what I am trying to do is create a batch file that when run will always delete a specific file if its size is larger than 100mb.

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%a in ("c:\somewhere\theFile.txt") do if %%~za gtr 104857600 del "%%~fa"
```

The `for` command will get a reference to the indicated file in its replaceable parameter `%%a`. Then `%%~za` will return the size of the referenced file, and `%%~fa` is the file name with full path.